# My Side Navigation Push bar is not toggling

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I dont know why my code is not working the fa-times and fa-bars are not open and close I think there is problem in jquery code please help me out.

```
<i class="fa fa-bars toggle_menu"></i> <div class="sidebar"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i> <center><br><img src="http://cpi.caribbeanprocurementinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/logo-2.png"> </center> <ul> <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Home</a></li> <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Who We Are</a></li> <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">What We Do</a></li> <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Blog</a></li> <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Contact Us</a></li> </ul> </div> <script type="text/jscript">

    $("fa-times").click(function(){
        $("toggle_menu").hide(); });

    $("fa-bars").click(function(){
        $("sidebar").show(); });

    </script> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"> </script> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Navigation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htE5f.png)

Comment: use `.` dot for class  `.fa-times` , `.toggle_menu` ... and if your click event before including jquery you need to wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){  // code here })`

Comment: i cant understand can you please edit my code,please @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: i edit it but still not working

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

use . dot for class `.fa-times` , `.toggle_menu` ... and if your click event before including jquery you need to wrap your code inside $(document).ready(function(){ // code here })

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <i class="fa fa-bars toggle_menu"></i> <div class="sidebar"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i> <center><br><img src="http://cpi.caribbeanprocurementinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/logo-2.png"> </center> <ul> <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Home</a></li> <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Who We Are</a></li> <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">What We Do</a></li> <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Blog</a></li> <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Contact Us</a></li> </ul> </div> 
    <script type="text/jscript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".fa-times").click(function(){
            $(".sidebar").hide(); 
          });
          $(".fa-bars").click(function(){
            $(".sidebar").show(); 
          });
      });
     </script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"> </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

```css
.sidebar{ 
 position:fixed; 
 top:30px; width:250px; 
 height:100vh;
 max-height:100vh; 
 overflow:hidden; 
 background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17,0.9); 
 opacity:0.9; 
 transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
 right : -250px; 
}

.sidebar.show{
  right : 0px;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle_menu{
 z-index:1000000;
 font-size:3em;
 position:fixed;
 float:right;
 right:10px;
 top:30px;
 padding:15px 20px 15px 15px;
 margin-top:0px;
 color:black;
 cursor:pointer;
 opacity:0.9;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle_menu.convert{
  right : 250px;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<html>
       <head>
          <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"> </script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <i class="fa fa-bars toggle_menu"></i> 
          <div class="sidebar"> 
          <center><br><img src="http://cpi.caribbeanprocurementinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/logo-2.png"> </center> 
          <ul> 
          <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Home</a></li> 
          <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Who We Are</a></li> 
          <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">What We Do</a></li> 
          <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Blog</a></li> 
          <li><a href="" style="color:#FFF;">Contact Us</a></li> 
          </ul> 
          </div>
        <script type="text/jscript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".toggle_menu").click(function(){
                $(".sidebar").toggleClass('show'); 
                $(".toggle_menu").toggleClass(' convert fa-bars fa-times'); 
              });
          });
         </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't think so @Faiza .. please wait for demo

Comment: while you got `$ is not a function` that means jquery is not included correctly

Comment: its working thank you so much May Allah bless you :) @ Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: @ Mohamed-Yousef i want to hide this section by default how can I?

Comment: @Faiza see my snippet above .. you need only to add the css part .. in css add `.sidebar{ display : none;}`

Comment: .sidebar{
 position:fixed;
 top:30px;
 right:0px;
 width:250px;
    height:100vh;
 max-height:100vh;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17,0.9);
 opacity:0.9;
 transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

Comment: i have this code in sidebar class may i delete this?

Comment: @Faiza no don't delete it just add line in this class with `display : none;`

Comment: can you give me any reference for animation

Comment: @Faiza  while you need a good animation it'll be better to work with `right` on css instead of `display : none;`  and work with add/removeClass on js  check my updated demo

Comment: http://raiseapp.xthemeapollo.com/digital-agency/   it would be something like this

Comment: @Faiza I updated my answer with new demo .. check it .. and please no more questions .. Good Luck :-)